# DataBinder.Eval data item Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, databinder

I am having trouble trying to figure on how to hide a ',' when the DataItem is empty.

Basically, I have table row that displays Registered Address and populated using the following technique:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address_Line_1" )%>,
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address_Line_2")%>,
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TOWNLAND")%>,                          
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CITY")%>,
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "STATE")%>,
```

Now if one or many of the above DataItem comes back as Empty then on the front end
it is displayed as

> Address 1, , , CITY, ,

I tried the following to hide the comma (',') but I keep getting an error saying

> Missing ')' 
>   on the first line of 'If' statement

```
<%#IIf(IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "STATE")) OrElse 

String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "STATE")) , "" , 

DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "STATE") & ",")%>
```

I am not sure whether my 'if' statement is wrong or It can't be done as above?

Anybody have suggestions about the above or any other alternative way of hiding the comma if a NULL value?

Comment: Isn't `IIf` from PHP? I remember using it a long time ago, but not on what language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address_Line_1") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address_Line_1").ToString()) ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address_Line_1").ToString() + "," : "" %>
```

*condition ? true : false*

Comment: Hi Melancia, thank you for the quick reply. The above code is giving the following error 
CS1011: Empty character literal

Comment: I guess was the single quote use. Try now.

Comment: Hi Melancia you were correct about the quotes but I have another error as shown below:

CS1501: No overload for method 'IsNullOrEmpty' takes '0' arguments

Comment: Sorry @Kevin. I've fixed it now. Long time since I've played with this.

Comment: Hi Melancia thanks again for the swift reply.
But I get another error System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

I am just thinking do we need to be a IsDBNull check instead?

Comment: On the answer I've proposed I couldn't know your DB structure and details, so feel free to adjust the code. You can check for `null` values, etc. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can call methods in code-behind so you can take this logic out of your markup, like this:

```
protected string GetAddress()
{
    string boundAddressValue = Eval("Address_Line_1") as string;

    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(boundAddressValue) ? boundAddressValue : String.Empty;
}
```

Now you can call it via markup like this:

```
<%# GetAddress() %>
```

Note: The downside to this approach is that if you call `GetAddress` outside of data-binding, then `Eval` will blow up, but it makes your markup much cleaner and you gain the help of the editor to help with syntax issues.

Comment: Thanks Karl I will try your solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

just Use

```
(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ColumnName") ?? "AnyValueAccordingToColumnDataTyle")
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but how about something like

```
protected string GetAddress()
{
    var parts = new List<string>(new string[] 
    {
         Eval("Address_Line_1") as string,
         Eval("Address_Line_2") as string,
         Eval("TOWNLAND") as string,                          
         Eval("CITY") as string,
         Eval("STATE") as string
    });

    return string.Join(", ", parts.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray());
}
```

// or

```
protected string JoinEval(string delim, param string[] fields)
{
    var parts = new List<string>();
    foreach (string field in fields)
    {
         string value = Eval(field).ToString();
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
              parts.Add(value);
    }

    return string.Join(delim, parts.ToArray());
}
```